# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am sending message to user using jQuery / Ajax. It's successfully sending the message to recipient but I can't see success message and in console log it's showing me following error message :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

**Message should be show here :**

```
$output .= '<div style="display:none;margin-top:10px;" class="sppb-ajax-contact-status"></div>';
```

**jQuery Code :**

```
//Ajax Contact Form
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('submit', '.sppb-ajaxt-contact-form', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var $self   = $(this);
        var value   = $(this).serializeArray();
        var request = {
            'option' : 'com_sppagebuilder',
            'task' : 'ajax',
            'addon' : 'ajax_contact',
            'data'   : value
        };

        $.ajax({
            type   : 'POST',
            data   : request,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $self.find('.fa').addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $self.find('.fa-spin').removeClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
                $self.trigger('reset');
                alert(response);
                $self.next('.sppb-ajax-contact-status').html($.parseJSON(response).data).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut(500);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

What's wrong here ?

Comment: The response is HTML, not JSON. Calling `$.parseJSON` on that is not going to go well.

Comment: To add on to what Rory said above, I've seen this when something is misconfigured for an endpoint, and I get back a 404 html response instead of the json response I expected from the endpoint.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Then what should I do ?

Comment: Either remove `$.parseJSON`, or return JSON from your AJAX request

Comment: Now testing purpose I am using this line : `alert( $self.next('.sppb-ajax-contact-status').html(response.data) );` and it's return `[object Object]`

Comment: Using this line : `alert( $self.next('.sppb-ajax-contact-status').html(response.data).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut(500) );` it's showing [object Object]